# Why does vb.net allow class names to be parameter names?

Tags: c#, vb.net, oop

I have seen a `Sub` which looked like this:

```
Private Sub DoSomething(ByRef PlaceHolder As PlaceHolder)
    'Do something with the PlaceHolder object
End Sub
```

I wonder why is this allowed. I can name a few languages where this is not allowed. I would like to be able to have methods with the very same return, parameters and names if one of them is `Shared`, the other is instance-level.

For example, let us suppose there is a `Class` named `Bird` and there is an object like this

```
Dim bird = New Bird("Duck Doggers")
```

`bird.fly()` would make sure that Duck Doggers flies, however, `Bird.fly()` would make all the birds fly, if, for instance an `IEnumerable` would be updated upon each constructor run of `Bird` and `Bird.fly` would iterate that `IEnumerable` and call `fly` for each item. As far as I can see, this is impossible in vb.net, since fly would be either `Shared` or instance-level. Is there any possible problem (besides unclarity) if a parameter name is the very same as the `Class` name whose instance is the said parameter?

I do not have C# in front of me, but I wonder whether naming of a parameter exactly as a `Class` is possible there.

Comment: You are asking different questions in each paragraph. Using the same name for a static and instance method has nothing to do with parameter names and is an ugly design anyway. Where is `fly()` goind to find all instances? Using a list to store all instances simply guarantees a memory leak - what if the constructor throws?

Comment: In VB, if you need to call a shared member that conflicts with an instance member, you just qualify the class name with the namespace.  If there is no conflict, the call to the shared member just "passes through" the instance member to the shared one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, actually, I am analyzing possible problems possibly coming from parameter name and class name match. What if your parameter is ByRef Bird As Bird and you call Bird.fly?

Comment: @LajosArpad then you have a bad design. It should be `FlyAll()` at least.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, I criticized someone for having the very same parameter name as a class name and I wonder whether there could be problems from this on technical level, or is it just ugly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have started the question with "I have seen a Sub". I would never write such a Sub, but I have been wondering about the problem when you have the very same name of a parameter as a class name. I know it is a bad design and would never do it, but wonder whether there might be problems besides uglyness and unclarity.

Comment: It's just ugly.  This is a very common VB pattern, and if you have used VB for a long time, you learn the pattern quickly, and it just becomes second nature.  I've been doing a mix of VB and C# for over 10 years now, and never hit any technical problems from this.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, if it is just ugly, then it is a relief for me, even though I will never write code in this way.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, that probably means that instance lefel fly() and shared fly() with the same parameters and return are not possible. Because if that was possible, then this kind of parameter naming could be problematic.

Comment: I think the main reason it is allowed is because VB isn't case sensitive.  Since `duck` and `Duck` refer to the same thing, you would have to come up with some very awkward looking variable or class names to avoid sharing the name.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, very interesting. I was not aware that it is case insensitive. So bird As Bird is the very same thing as Bird As Bird?

Comment: Yep, same thing.  If you auto format the code in Visual Studio it will correct the case for you to match how it was declared.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, I guess my question is answered: VB is case-insensitive and that is probably the cause this is allowed. fly needs to be either instance-level or Shared and variable declarations like Dim foo As Foo should be avoided, as they are equivalent to Dim Foo As Foo.

Comment: I don't know if I would forbid it as a blanket policy.  You will just end up with something even more crazy to keep the names distinct, like Hungarian Notation, and no one wants that.  Like I said earlier, if you use VB for any length of time it just becomes 2nd nature and becomes easy to read and understand.  I wouldn't say it's better or worse than what C# allows, it's just different.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, if you convert your comments to an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I'm writing up some quick example code to illustrate how the different calls work.  It'll be up in a few minutes.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, thanks for the instructive comments and helpful attitude, I will read the answer with great interest.

Comment: There is just no point in disallowing it.  Imagine the terrible hardship on the .NET designers if they couldn't use simple names for simple classes like Array and String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common naming pattern to the majority of VB developers.  Much of it stems from VB being case-insensitive.  Without being allowed to name variables this way, either the variable, or the class name would have to be renamed "creatively" to avoid conflicts, that just leads to things like Hungarian Notation, or other strange naming patterns.  While it may look odd to someone who isn't used to it, it quickly becomes 2nd nature to a VB developer.  Calling a `shared` member on an instance variable just "passes though" to the shared member, as in the following example.

```
Public Class Bird
    public Shared sub Fly
        Debug.WriteLine("Fly called from Shared")
    End sub

    public sub Quack
        Debug.WriteLine("Quack called from Instance")
    End sub

End Class

Public Class Main
    public sub Test(bird As Bird)
        bird.Fly()
        Bird.Fly()

        bird.Quack()
        Bird.Quack()
    End sub
End Class
```

Calling `Test` results in the following output.

> Fly called from Shared
>
> Fly called from Shared
>
> Quack called from Instance
>
> Quack called from Instance

Comment: Except that the IDE would auto-correct these so that you would always see "Bird.Fly()", not "bird.Fly()", and you would always see "bird.Quack()", and not "Bird.Quack()".

Comment: Correct.  I had to turn off auto formatting to get the text to show up this way in order to show that it still compiles and works with different cases.